# How to assign string object to observable<string>

Tags: typescript

I am trying to convert a string observable to a plain string for firestore.

Tried foreach method

```
this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      tap(snap => {
        if (snap.bytesTransferred === snap.totalBytes) {
          // Update firestore on completion
          this.afs.collection('logos').add({ path, size: snap.totalBytes });
        }
      }),
      finalize(() => this.logoURL = this.storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL() )
```

```
this.logoURL.forEach(value => { this.imagePath = value.toString(); }
```

I would like to get the value from logoUrl and store it in imagePath

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      tap(snap => {
        if (snap.bytesTransferred === snap.totalBytes) {
          // Update firestore on completion
          this.afs.collection('logos').add({ path, size: snap.totalBytes });
        }
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        this.logoURL = this.storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL();
        this.logoURL.subscribe(val => {
          this.imagePath = val;
        });
      })
    );
```